# Can I use reference to Jackson ObjectMapper when I registered JacksonFeature for JerseyTest?

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jersey-test-framework

Is it possible somehow to reuse Jackson ObjectMapper reference in my test classes when I testing my rest services using Jersey test framework.

I registered JacksonFeature in my abstract class from which my test classes extends.

```
public abstract class AbstractRestIntegrationTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {

        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(getResourceClass());
        resourceConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
        resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return resourceConfig;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In my test class I calling the rest service, which returns to me json. Then I want to parse this json by jackson and check if it contains objects. And my question is if I can reuse that ObjectMapper in test method from Jersey when I register JacksonFeature.

```
public class ManagedElementIntegrationTest extends AbstractRestIntegrationTest {

       @Override
    protected Class<?> getResourceClass() {
        return ManagedElementRestService.class;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetManagedElementById() throws IOException {
        IManagedElementService managedElementService = getBeanOfClass(IManagedElementService.class);

        ManagedElement me = prepareManagedElementObject();

        try {
            when(managedElementService.getUpdatedApplication(anyString())).thenReturn(me);
        } catch (ManagedElementNotFoundException e) {
            fail("Exception not expected: " + e);
        }

        String response = target("me/app").request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(response);
        assertNotNull(actualObj);
        assertNotNull(actualObj.get("mapPosition"));
        assertNull(actualObj.get("alarms"));

        // code continues below.
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to use it?

Comment: I edited my question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: You don't need to use the ObjectMapper. You just need to use `response.readEntity(JsonNode.class)`

Comment: Thank you, it's working.